# Vector index "out of bounds" when converting large floating point numbers to integer indices

Tags: rust

I've been trying to generate primes between m and n with the following function:

```
//the variable sieve is a list of primes between 1 and 32000
//The primes up to 100 are definitely correct
fn sieve_primes(sieve: &Vec<usize>, m: &usize, n: &usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let size: usize = *n - *m + 1;
    let mut list: Vec<usize> = Vec::with_capacity(size);

    for i in *m..(*n + 1) {
        list.push(i);
    }   
    for i in sieve {
        for j in ( ((*m as f32) / (*i as f32)).ceil() as usize)..( (((*n as f32) / (*i as f32)).floor() + 1.0) as usize) {
                println!("{} ",j);
                if j != 1 {list[i * j - *m] = 0;} 
        }
    }   

    let mut primes: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
    for num in &list{
        if *num >= 2 {primes.push(*num);}
    }   
    primes
}
```

This works for smaller (less than 1000000-ish) values of m and n, but 
it fails at runtime for numbers around the billions / hundred-millions.

The output for m = 99999999, n = 100000000 is:

> 33333334
>   thread '' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 2 but the index is 3'

If you look at the numbers this doesn't make any sense. First of all, it seems to skip the number 2 in the list of primes. Second, when i = 3 the for statement should simplify to `for j in 33333333..333333334`, which for some reason starts j at 33333334.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting integers to `f32`, but `f32` is not precise enough. Use `f64` instead.

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", 33333333.0f32); // prints 33333332
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`f32` can only represent all 24-bit integers exactly, which corresponds to about 16 million (actually 16777216). Above that there are gaps, up to 33554432 only even numbers can be represented.  So in your example 33333333 cannot be represented as `f32` and is rounded to 33333334.

You don't need to use float to round the result of an integer division. Using integers directly is both faster and doesn't have precision issues. For non-negative integers you can do the following:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 12;
    let b = 7;
    println!("rounded down: {}", a / b);
    println!("rounded:      {}", (a + b / 2) / b);
    println!("rounded up:   {}", (a + b - 1) / b);
}
```